# The 'ehcahce' package(org.springframework.cache.ehcache) is removed from spring-context-support 6.0.x version. What is an alternative to the package?

Tags: spring, ehcache

I am using the ehcache package from the spring-context-support JAR in my code. In the 6.0.x version, then entire package has been removed(refer to SS below).
[spring-context-support 6.0.x git repo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrHil.png)
I am looking for an alternative to this package or if it's present elsewhere.

I've tried searching for its alternative or if it has been moved to some other package as this has been done before as well. I tried searching the list of deprecated classes in 6.0.x, but classes of this package aren't mentioned there so I couldn't find a solution there as well.

Comment: You should configure EhCache through the JCache API.